# many buttons with the same name

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript

I have a bunch of buttons with the same name, but different values. These buttons need to change from one value to another and back when clicked. I know I can do it using html and javascript, but I want to do it with as little code as possible. I have 13 buttons and I don't want to call 13 different `onclick` functions. I was hoping to use a case statement with the element ids, but I don't know I where to begin. I would post my code, but it's so simple I doubt it's needed.

Here's an example of what my code for the buttons looks like:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="test1" name="Online">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="test2" name="Online">
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Can you explain what it is you want a little more clearly? I'm not entirely sure what it is you're asking for.  Could you provide and example explaining what you would like to happen?

Comment: so basically its a tool report so i have a list of tools and next to the list is a button that says online. well on click id like for it to change to offline. id like this to happen with all the buttons i have but without having to make a bunch of functions. to reduce the functions id like to use the same name for every button. i am open to changing the script to get it to work so any help would be great.

Comment: Do you want to change the value of `value` or the value of `name` on your buttons when they are clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your buttons have the same name, you won't be able to use the default OnClick event (in this case `Online_OnClick`). If you try, only the *last* button will fire the event. But you can use the `onclick` attribute to specify a function to call. For example:

```
<input type="button" value="test1" name="Online" onclick="DoButtonClick('test1')">
<input type="button" value="test2" name="Online" onclick="DoButtonClick('test2')">

<script language="vbscript">
    Sub DoButtonClick(strButtonValue)

        ' Do what you wish

    End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: so anything within ''  can be the variable i want to pass? so i can add a select case based off the strbuttonvalue?

Comment: just tested it seriously huge deal you have no idea. this will change everything i should get rid of some serious redundent code . thanks so much for you help SIR!

Comment: If you use `this` instead of `'test1'`, you get the object passed to your sub as argument, so `strButtonValue` would become `objButton`. The value of that object can be read by `objButton.value`.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos That will work also. But you can't use `this` in VBScript. You must pass `Me` instead (since IE9, I believe).

Comment: @Bond When the `DoButtonClick` _call_ is in VBScript context, then you have to use `me`, but here the _call_ context is Javascript (you can spot that by the single quotes around the argument). The function definition however is in VBScript.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos I'm not sure I would say the *call* is in JavaScript. VBScript supports single quote arguments as well, which is why the code above works fine. When you're working with IE, which supports both JavaScript and VBScript, I would say the call is language *neutral*. But regardless, what I'm saying is that you can't replace `'test1'` with `this`, as you suggested, because `this` does not work with VBScript, regardless the calling context.

Comment: @Bond as far a I know, this won't work: `onclick="VBScript:DoButtonClick('test1')"` because single quotes have a different meaning in VBScript, therefore I think it is Javascript, but correct me if I'm wrong. You can pass a Javascript object with `this` to a VBScript function. The VBScript function just accepts the object and you can use properties or call methods on it, like `receivedObject.Click`

Comment: @AutomatedChaos This works: `onclick="MsgBox('Hello')"` and that's clearly VBScript.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos My guess is that the `onclick` string is "eval'd" instead of used literally. So that's why you can get away with using single-quote params in VBScript. In other words, IE might be doing `Execute("MsgBox('Hello')")`.

Comment: @Bond I did not know the single quotes worked, nice trick. However `onclick="MsgBox('Hello')"` only works if you have set your scripting language to VBScript before (by having the script language set in a script tag above it). In a plain new HTML file it won't, just try it in a new file. And you can pass `this` to a VBScript function, try it as `onclick="javascript:PassOn(this)"` <-javascript call to a VBScript function `sub PassOn(o) : msgbox o.value : end sub`

Comment: @AutomatedChaos Good stuff. I just did some additional testing myself. In the absence of a `javascript:` or `vbscript:` qualifier, it looks like the language used in the first script block determines how the language is interpreted in inline statements (like event handlers). I created JS and VBS `script` blocks in the same doc. If the JS `script` block appeared first, inline code was treated as JS (and `this` needed to be used). If the VBS `script` block appeared first, inline code was treated as VBS (and 'Me' needed to be used, even when calling a JavaScript function!).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to do anything server-side, you can do this using just javascript. I've posted an example of how to do this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jpdurham/9HgLw/).

First, just add an `onclick` event that passes the current element along to a function, say `clicked()`.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input onclick="clicked(this)" type="button" value="test1" name="Online">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input onclick="clicked(this)" type="button" value="test2" name="Online">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's what the javascript `clicked()` function would look like

```
function clicked(elem) {
    if (elem.name === 'Online') {
        elem.name = 'Offline';
        // do other stuff
    } else {
        elem.name = 'Online';
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```